# How can I use an npm package with certain inputs from a .ts file class?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-ses

Background information:
I am trying to use an npm package to send emails through AWS SES from within my ionic application.  I would like to use the npm package "node-ses" which using an email sending API method from AWS.

Information: https://github.com/aheckmann/node-ses#readme

I need to use this code to create and send the email:

```
var ses = require('node-ses')
  , client = ses.createClient({key: 'key', secret: 'secret'});
 
// Give SES the details and let it construct the message for you.
client.sendEmail({
   to: 'blah@gmail.com'
 , from: 'email@mail.com'
 , cc: 'whatever@m.net'
 , bcc: ['a@b.com', 'c@d.org']
 , subject: 'greetings'
 , message: 'your <b>message</b> goes here'
 , altText: 'plain text'
}, function (err, data, res) {
 // ...
});
```

How would I do this from within the .ts file that I have which has the necessary information? I would like to insert the necessary information from variables that contain info such as the "to" email or the "message".  Do I somehow put create a file with a template for the email code below that I can somehow call from my .ts file with inputs?  I am lost.  Any information about this is greatly appreciated.  I do not understand how the files can fit together, as I cannot use this code from within the class I have within the .ts file.

Thanks!